# Programatically changing the connection string in web.config file

Tags: asp.net, security, web.config-transform

In my asp.net application, at first time launching the application, if there is no database connections provided, it will redirect to separate page asks for entering the database  details, if they provide valid details, we have to create the new database and need to use that connection string through out the application.

Here what my scenario is, after creating the database i stored the connection string in web.config file programmatically, but when i trying to reuse the connection string it showing the empty string.

I come to know that web.config file only gives the values what we provide at compile time. To overcome this situation i go for XML files to store connection string  which is not secured to store the secured and sensitive information. Because my application should have the capability to change the connection string from front end.

My questions are:

1. Is there any way to store the connection string securely,and that to have to change dynamically if change from the application.
2. I can access my XML file though browser, and can view all connection details, how can i restrict to access the XML file from the URL.

and any other better solution is appreciated.

Comment: _"and i come to know that web.config file only gives the values what we provide at compile time"_ - that is not how `*.config` files work. Focus on the config issue, you should be able to update a config file from code and read the new value at runtime. Create a small program to resolve that issue, then incorporate it in your project. You need to show your (relevant!) code if you want anyone to be able to help solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1 ) Is there any way to store the connection string securely,and that to have to change dynamically if change from the application.

Why not store the connection string encrypted? The connection string is just a string, so you could store it in XML or even another database. You will need to make your code read this as the connection string rather than one from `web.config`. There is no requirement for an ASP.NET application to read connection strings from `web.config`.

> 2) I can access my XML file though browser, and can view all connection details, how can i restrict to access the XML file from the URL.

Store your file within `/App_Data` - this is a specially protected .NET folder that does not allow access via the web server. i.e. `http://www.example.com/App_Data/foo.xml` cannot be read.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, surely i will try to implement it, I asking this, because if there any alternatives.